# Model Method from rest_framework modelSerializer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

this is a simple question but I'm very new to django-rest-framework.

I was wondering if there is any way to access a method defined on the model from the serializer.?

Say I have a model

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    listingid           = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    mappingid           = models.BigIntegerField()
    projectlevelid      = models.IntegerField()
    subsellerid         = models.IntegerField()
    iscreatedbyadmin    = models.BooleanField(default=None, null=True)
    createdon           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    validationstatus    = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def is_project(self):
        """ Returns True if listing is of Project Type (projectlevelid=6) else False""" 
        if self.projectlevelid == 6:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_project_info(self):
        """Returns False if listing is not mapped to a project, else returns the project info"""
        if self.is_project() == False:
            return False
        return models.Project.objects.get(projectid=self.mappingid)
```

**Is it possible for the serializer**

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.MasterListing
```

**to have access to `Listing.is_project` i.e. for an object of the `Listing` model, can the serializer call its `is_project` method?**

If so, can I set a field in the serializer such that if `is_project` returns true, the field is populated?
I am trying for something like this,

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = serializers.SomeRELATEDFieldTYPE()    # this field if populated if the `is_project` is true

    class Meta:
        model = models.MasterListing
```

I understand I can do this using some combination of `required=False` and `SerializerMethodField`, but maybe there is a simpler way?.

Note: It is not possible for me to set a foreign key to the `mappingid`, since it depends on the `projectlevelid`. I also can't affect this relationship so no further normalization is possible. I know that there might be some way using content-types, but we are trying to avoid that if it is possible..

---

**EDIT**: I solved the problem, but not as the question specified.
I used this:

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_project(self, obj):
        """Returns False if listing is not mapped to a project, else returns the project info"""
        if str(obj.projectlevelid) == str(6):
            projectObj = models.Project(projectid=obj.mappingid)
            projectObjSerialized = ProjectSerializer(projectObj)
            return projectObjSerialized.data
        return False

    class Meta:
        model = models.MasterListing
```

**So, the original question still stands: "Is it possible for the modelSerializer to access its models methods?"**

Also, another problem that now appears is, **can I make the serializer exclude fields on demand, i.e. can it exclude `mappingid` and `projectlevelid` if it is indeed a project?**

Comment: You can use `fields` under `class Meta:` to control which fields should be included http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-should-be-included

Comment: this allows you to exclude them but not dynamically exclude. he wants exclude only when is_project value is false

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For your first question [source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) attribute is the answer, citing:

> May be a method that only takes a self argument, such as
>   URLField('get_absolute_url')

For your second answer, yes it is also possible. Check the example it provides in their docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

*PS: I really love drf for its very complete documentation =).*

**EDIT**

To use the source attribute you can just declare a new explicit field like so:

```
is_project = serializers.BooleanField(source='is_project')
```

With this, is_project field has the value of the is_project method of your instance. Having this, when creating the dynamic serializer (by modifying its init method) you can add the 'project' field if it's True.

Comment: *"PS: I really love drf for its very complete documentation =)."* Duly noted :)
But can you provide an example on how to implement source? Because the method corresponding to `SerializerMethodField` gets an object of the serializer instance, I was wondering how to get the same using `source`?

Comment: I've edited the answer, since source is a core argument of the serializer Field class, you can use it with any subclass like CharField, BooleanField, etc.

Answer (score 5):

@argaen is absolutely right, `source` is a DRF core argument, and would most definitely solve your problem. However, it's redundant to use `source`, if the field name is the same as the `source`. So the above answer won't require you specify `source`, since `field` name `is_project` is the same as `source` name `is_project`.

So in your case:

```
is_project = serializers.BooleanField()
```